# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.File

Tags: java

He cargado todos los **.txt** de un directorio de mi equipo en un `combobox`. Al seleccionar cada **.txt** del `combobox`, quiero imprimir el texto en el `textarea`.

**Variables:**

```
String ubicacion = "C:\\Users\\Nombre\\Desktop";
File contenedor = new File(ubicacion);
File[] registros = contenedor.listFiles();
```

**Código mostrarCombo:**

```
private void MostrarCombo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
        if (registros[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            combobox.addItem(registros[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**Código leer/abrir fichero:**

```
   public String abrirFichero(File fichero) {
        String documento = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fichero), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            int ascci;

            while ((ascci = br.read()) != -1) {
                char c = (char) ascci;
                documento += c;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return documento;
    }
```

**Código al cambiar de item en el combobox:**

```
   private void comboboxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          
        File fichero = (File) combobox.getSelectedItem();
        if (fichero.canRead()) {
            if (fichero.getName().endsWith("txt")) {
                String documento = abrirFichero(fichero);
                area.setText(documento);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo no compatible.");
            }
        }
    }
```

No me lee el texto de los .txt en el textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta línea:

```
File fichero = (File) combobox.getSelectedItem();
```

Debería estar así:

```
File fichero = new File(combobox.getSelectedItem());
```

No se puede convertir un `String` en un objeto de tipo `File`,  pero sí puedes crear un objeto de tipo `File` a partir de un `String`

Comment: File fichero = new File((String) combobox.getSelectedItem()); Cierto, lo acabo de solucionar gracias a su respuesta. Lo que no entiendo es por qué no me lee los .txt, aún así.

Comment: @omaza1990 eso es porque la ruta no es la correcta. Si estás usando rutas relativas tienes que tener en cuenta el directorio de trabajo, ya que  se empieza a contar a partir de ese punto

Comment: No añadí todo el código... Añado la ruta absoluta, one second. Ya está modificada @eferion

Comment: No te abre los ficheros porque en la combo no te salen con la ruta. La función getName de la clase File te retorna el nombre pero no la ruta. Y cuando tomas los nombres de la combo y llamas a leer el fichero, le pasas solo el nombre sin la ruta.

Comment: Gracias chicos. Solventado: String ruta_absoluta = ubicacion+"\\"+combobox.getSelectedItem();
        File fichero = new File(ruta_absoluta);